# Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps

What is the difference between google apps and google app engine?

Answer (score 26):

[Google Apps](http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/business/) is a Web-based hosted [software-as-a-service (SaaS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SaaS) solution (gmail / docs / talk / site / calendar on your own domain).

[Google App Engine](https://code.google.com/appengine/docs/whatisgoogleappengine.html) is a [platform-as-a-service (PaaS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PaaS) solution. It is something like [EC2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Elastic_Compute_Cloud), but with only specific (Python, Java, PHP and Go) runtime environments available.

Comment: GAE is more like Amazon Beanstalk than EC2

Answer (score 5):

Google apps offers google web applications (gmail, docs, calendars, etc)
Google app engine is a service to host **your own web applications**

Answer (score 2):

See [this post](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/11833/whats-the-difference-between-google-apps-and-web-apps-on-the-chrome-web-store) on the webapps SE site describing the difference between the services.

Answer (score 2):

In simple words:

- With google apps you can get a set of work application such as Google Drive, Gmail, Calendar...
- With google app engine (GAE) you can create applications servers with little effort. There are others similar PaaS, heroku is one of the most famous.

Answer (score 1):

Google Apps is a suite of services for businesses and organizations. It includes: GMAIL, Google Drive, Calendar, Docs etc. Many of these applications are available separately with a standard Google Account.

Google App Engine is PaaS (Platform as a Service) solution. Google App Engine is a way to write your own Web applications and have them hosted on Google servers. Google App Engine customers are programmers who want a scalable platform for their Internet applications.

Answer (score -2):

Google App Engine is same as hosting, Google Apps is same as office softrawe
Google Apps include "Drive"  Drive is complete solution for office requirements. Spreadsheet,presentations,documents etc. and have extra properties as Form Builder (for simple data collection) and Cloud file storage. But Google apps haven't any solution alternatively to MS Access.